# How to insert (upsert) an object that has no external id?

Tags: rest-api, custom-object, fields, externalid, upsert

According to [this documentation](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/), you need to know the external ID field of an object to inset new records. For some of my custom objects, I'm not seeing any fields in the object description that have an `externalId` value of true (I'm logged in as an admin).

How do I insert a new record of an object that does't have an external ID field?

*Note: I don't have much control over the current object structure*

**Using REST API v31.0**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

REST API means that you can use 'GET', 'POST', 'PATCH' or 'DELETE' as HTTP methods for your requested resource. These methods correspond to what you're trying to achieve. GET = describe, POST = insert, PATCH = update, DELETE = delete. Here's an example of how to insert a new Account using the POST method:

```
POST /services/data/v31.0/sobjects/Account HTTP/1.1
Host: na15.salesforce.com
User-Agent: Guzzle/4.1.6 curl/7.30.0 PHP/5.4.24
Authorization: Bearer 00Di000000xxxxxx
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 24

{"Name":"New Account"}
```

Answer (score 2):

You do not need any ID at all to insert a record. Simply use the REST api and end the endpoint at

```
instance_url/services/data/v30.0/sobjects/{CustomObject__c}
```

Comment: Executing the above URL returns a "describe" of the object. And I wouldn't expect a GET request to add an object. Am I missing something?

Comment: @contactmatt - Um, thats why you use POST